# How to get rid of the global variables

Tags: python

I don't want to use the global-variable, but how do I make this without them? 
(I have more functions and so on, so this isn't all)

Players turn. I use the global-variable to make sure the turns are switching, tried some other sulotion however the turns didn't switch...

```
#Check if the shot hit any computerships
def player_hit_check():
    global players_turn
    shot = player_shot()
    check_if_hit = set(computer_ships) & set(player_turn_shot) 

    if(check_if_hit == set()):
        print("You missed! Switching turns...")
        time.sleep(3)
        players_turn = 1
    else:
        print(f"YOU MADE A BIG BANG ON ",player_turn_shot,"!") 
        computer_ships.remove(shot)
        all_player_hits.append(shot)
```

Computers turn

```
#Check if the computers shot hit any player ships
def computer_hit_check():
    global computers_turn
    computer_random_shot = computer_shot()
    check_if_hit = set(player_ships) & set(computer_turn_shot) 

    if(check_if_hit == set()):
        print("Computer missed! It's now your turn.")
        time.sleep(3)
        computers_turn = 1
    else:
        print(f"COMPUTER MADE A BIG BANG ON ",computer_turn_shot,"!") 
        player_ships.remove(computer_random_shot)
        all_computer_hits.append(computer_random_shot)
```

The game it self

```
#Runs the game
while True:
    #Players turn
    players_turn = 0
    while players_turn < 1:
        print('\n'.join('\t'.join(row) for row in board.values()))
        print("Playerships:",player_ships)
        print("Computerships:",computer_ships)
        print("You have shot on",all_player_shots,"and has knocked out these ships:",all_player_hits)
        print("The computer has shot at these coordinates",all_computer_shots,"and has knocked out these ships:",all_computer_hits)
        player_hit_check()

    #Computers turn
    computers_turn = 0
    while computers_turn < 1:
        computer_hit_check()
```

Comment: [Pass arguments to functions, and return values from functions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions).

Comment: Why does the turn variable need to be from outside? The way I see it, it can just be a local variable to the functions, and the loop should be inside the function. Then in your main code just call each function one after the other...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case you don't need global variables at all. Your program is not using them to carry information back and forth.

In your case you just need to get information back from your functions. So in the case of `player_hit_check()`:

```
def player_hit_check():
    shot = player_shot()
    check_if_hit = set(computer_ships) & set(player_turn_shot) 

    if(check_if_hit == set()):
        print("You missed! Switching turns...")
        time.sleep(3)
        return 1
    else:
        print(f"YOU MADE A BIG BANG ON ",player_turn_shot,"!") 
        computer_ships.remove(shot)
        all_player_hits.append(shot)
    return 0
```

And the call site would be like this:

```
while True:
    #Players turn
    players_turn = 0
    while players_turn < 1:
        # prints elided ...
        players_turn = player_hit_check()
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with global variables is, that they fly around in an unstructured manner.

There are several approaches to solve global variables

1. One first step to get rid of global variables is to use singletons (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern). This will bundle similar values into one class. So the values are more structured and easier to track.
2. Use classes. If the global value is used in an environment that can be associated to a single responsibility, it can be productive to bundle all functions in a class and make the global variable to a class variable or property of the class
3. Pass it through. In many programs there is the need of settings class or state class. Put everything in there that defines the current state or starting state of the program and pass it through your code. The downside of passing is, that this classes tend to become almighty classes that appear in every constructor.

There are certainly more approaches how to get rid of global variables, but this are some common strategies.